# Putty: Local port 80 forwarding to localhost:80 failed: Network error: Permission denied

Tags: windows-10, putty, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

In putty, I have the following:

- **Session**

  - hostname:username@azurecontainsersvc_mgmt.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com
  - port: 2200
- **Connection>SSH>Tunnels** L80 localhost:80
- **Connection>SSH>Auth Private key:** my_public_key.ppk

Ans when I connect, it asks me for my password, everything looks great, but I get access denied.  I have tried running as admin with the same results.

> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Connecting to [IP_Address] port 2200
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.69
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2
>   Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Using SSH protocol version 2
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and
>   hash SHA-256
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/ssh-rsa host
>   keys, but we don't know any of them
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Host key fingerprint is:
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   ssh-ed25519 256 [Fingerprint]
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server
>   encryption
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC
>   algorithm
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client
>   encryption
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC
>   algorithm
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Reading key file "C:\path_to_certs\privatekey.ppk"
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Offered public key
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:37   Offer of public key accepted
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:55   Sent public key signature
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:55   Access granted
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:55   Opening session as main channel
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:56   Opened main channel
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:56   Local port 80 forwarding to localhost:80 failed:
>   Network error: Permission denied
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:56   Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)
>
> 2017-05-02 11:28:56   Started a shell/command

Any ideas?  I am lost - thank you!

Not sure if it matters, but I am trying to connect to a DC/OS cluster on Azure: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-connect

Comment: You have mapped port 80 on the remote server to port 80 on your *own* system. It may be used by another application (Skype is often using it). It may also be reserved for use by an admin (listening on ports below 1000 is usually reserved and inaccessible for user applications). The remote server might also not allow you to map ports to your local system per its configuration.

Comment: how do I see what might be using that port?

Comment: Sorry, I'm on mobile but this site should help: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28609/how-can-i-tell-what-is-listening-on-a-tcpip-port-in-windows/.  Use `netstat`.